# Web application - automatically include files?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, vs-web-application-project

I am running a CMS as an ASP.NET WebApplication and want to automatically include all files generated by the CMS in the project folder to be included in the project.

By default they are excluded, and finding them by hand and including them every time a new file is created is annoying.

Is it possible to include new files in the web application folder by default?

Comment: Include them how?  Are they code files or data?

Answer (score 0):

Web Site Projects work that way, however I am not sure why you would want CMS generated content in your source code repository.